# Visual Studio debugging attach to process: any way to skip the "do you want to attach to this process" confirmation window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to disable this confirmation message in Visual Studio 2022 when attaching to a process? I understand why it is there, but for local development, it slows down my workflow because I often alt tab back to my browser right away and refreshing, thinking that I'll hit a breakpoint, but of course that won't happen until "Attach" is selected.

[image: do you want to attach to this process]

There is an option for this in VS, but it doesn't seem to work in my case, even after restarting VS:

[image: VS setting for disabling the warning]

The bit about "(Managed only)" gave me pause, but I am attaching to Managed (.NET 4.x) code, so this should work.

So far, the best workaround I have is the [ReAttach Visual Studio plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach) which allows me to reattach with a quick keyboard shortcut and no confirmation message:

[image: ReAttach Demo]